# Is the Cardano Token Registry on Github abandoned/problematic?

Tags: token, cardano-foundation

Pretty much what the title says, take a look:

[https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry/)

- There's pull requests 10s of days old,
- The CI system is failing  checks everywhere on erroneous data and mixing `json` files
- There only seems to be 1 single maintainer, **admin-cf**, who seems to be
  randomly picking PRs instead of maintaining a FIFO queue once every 7 days

Is the registry abandoned? Has there been another registry to replace it, and I'm looking at the old repo?

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://github.com/cardano-foundation/cardano-token-registry/issues/1114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository is not abandoned, it is maintained by the Cardano Foundation right now.